# <input type='textarea' onmousemove='toscheck()' /> isn't working only on Firefox

Tags: firefox, textarea, onmousemove, javascript

For some reason, this code works all chrome, safari, and ei but not on firefox.

```
        <script type="text/javascript">
        function toscheck(){
        if(tos.scrollTop+540 > tos.scrollHeight){
            alert(tos.scrollTop + " " + tos.scrollHeight);
        }
    }
        </script>

----------

    <textarea name="tos" id="tos" readonly="readonly"  onmousemove="toscheck()">text</textarea>
```

Nothing's triggered on FF but works fine on all other browsers.

However, `<textarea.. onmousemove=alert('test')>text</textarea>` works fine.

I'm new to javascript so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Your function is missing a closing brace}

Comment: @Vince it was actually just bad formatting.  I fixed it for him.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Live example](http://www.jsfiddle.net/subhaze/fdZJj/)

Other than your missing `}` to close out your function it seems to work in FF for me.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function toscheck(){
        if(tos.scrollTop+540 > tos.scrollHeight){
            alert(tos.scrollTop + " " + tos.scrollHeight);
        }
    } // <----- was missing
</script>
```

---

Also, in your function you directly go to `tos.property`.

You'll either need to pass `this` into the `mousemove="toscheck(this)"` and have your function setup like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function toscheck(elem){
        if(elem.scrollTop+540 > elem.scrollHeight){
            alert(elem.scrollTop + " " + elem.scrollHeight);
        }
    }
</script>
```

Or get your textarea from within the function like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function toscheck(){
        var tos = document.getElementById('tos');
        if(tos.scrollTop+540 > tos.scrollHeight){
            alert(tos.scrollTop + " " + tos.scrollHeight);
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: I looked at your live example and saw that i needed function toscheck(tos){...}
and
onmousemove="toscheck(this)"
Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 2):

That should actually not work in any browser. There is a closing bracket missing in your Javascript code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function toscheck() {
  if (tos.scrollTop + 540 > tos.scrollHeight) {
    alert(tos.scrollTop + " " + tos.scrollHeight);
  }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Best solution, use jQuery and it's automatically cross-browser method or see [this page](http://iescripts.org/help/crossbrowser.html) regarding making that code cross-browser compatible due to differences between implementation in re:

```
Scrolling offset - how much the page has scrolled.

var x,y;
if (self.pageYOffset) // all except Explorer
{
    x = self.pageXOffset;
    y = self.pageYOffset;
}
else if (document.documentElement &amp;&amp; document.documentElement.scrollTop)
    // Explorer 6 Strict
{
    x = document.documentElement.scrollLeft;
    y = document.documentElement.scrollTop;
}
else if (document.body) // all other Explorers
    {
        x = document.body.scrollLeft;
        y = document.body.scrollTop;
    }
```

and

```
var x,y;
    var test1 = document.body.scrollHeight;
    var test2 = document.body.offsetHeight
    if (test1 &gt; test2) // all but Explorer Mac
    {
        x = document.body.scrollWidth;
        y = document.body.scrollHeight;
    }
    else // Explorer Mac;
         //would also work in Explorer 6 Strict, Mozilla and Safari
    {
        x = document.body.offsetWidth;
        y = document.body.offsetHeight;
    }
```

Comment: You're aware that we're talking about a `textarea` - not a whole document (in an `iframe` for example)?

Comment: right, I copied over the code from the page that discussed the cross-browser issues with using the plain JS methods.. but I first recommended that jQuery be used since it handles that all internally... the code example relates only to the cross-browser differences, not the actual code needed as learning how and why is better than just dropping in correct code.

Answer (score 0):

How big is your actual text box? Maybe it's rendered in a different size than you expect and/or the scrollheight is a little bit different? Maybe it's a font size/resolution/DPI setting issue. To try to solve it, add a small overlapping amount so you actually don't have to scroll to the absolute bottom (won't work in IE for example when using keyboard navigation and Ctrl + End).

```
if(tos.scrollTop + 565 > tos.scrollHeight){
```

On a side note, I wouldn't check this in `onmousemove` as people might use keyboard keys to navigate as well. I'd suggest using `onblur` and maybe `onmouseup` and/or `onkeyup`. `onmouseup` however might not fire if the mouse button is released while being on the scroll bar.